# Does poll(2) wait for an operation on a fd to be finished?

Tags: linux, process

What I mean to ask is: Let's say a process calls poll(fd array), waiting for any of those file descriptors to be written to. And let's say another process writes to one of those file descriptors. Can I be sure that the second process will finish writing before poll() returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the type of the underlying pseudofile.

For byte-oriented (character devices), all you know when `poll` returns is that there is some data to read, not that any particular boundary has been reached.  In particular, it doesn't wait for the "sender process finished writing" boundary, or even the "all data from a single `write()` call" boundary.  Boundaries are not preserved.

For message queues (in Win32 this is a pipe with `PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE`) and datagram sockets, then message boundaries are preserved and the entire argument of a `write()` (or `send` or `sendto`) call will appear atomically at the destination, `poll()` won't trigger until the whole datagram is transferred.

Comment: I have to poll on a set of pipes, so I'm guessing this falls under the second case

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio: Most pipes are byte-oriented.  The second case (final paragraph) only applies to datagram-oriented pipes.

Comment: Which would be an example of a datagram oriented pipe then?

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio: `mq_open` in Linux, or `PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE` flag used with Win32 pipe functions.

Comment: How do i know whether something is byte or datagram oriented? I was going to use a named pipe/fifo, but I also want to make sure poll returns only after a process has finished writing

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio: What does it mean for a writer to have finished?  If the other process exited, clearly it is done, but what if it is still running?  It closed its handle to the pipe?  In either of these cases you will receive SIGPIPE... so wait on that not on data ready.  If the other process still has the handle open, you cannot know it is "finished" without looking at the data.  Even with a message-oriented pseudofile, you only can distinguish separate `write()` calls, you cannot look into the future to see if `write()` is called again later.

Comment: I meant that a single write() call has finished. I have a master process with 10 slaves. Whenever a slave writes on a fd, I want the master process to process that data. But I want to make sure that the slave has finished writing

Comment: On linux you can create a boundary-preserving "pipe" with `socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0, sp)`. The semantics would be a bit different from a regular pipe or a stream socket, though -- a `write()` too big will fail with `EMSGSIZE` instead of blocking.